# getting a value from a resultset with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

In my model I have this snippet

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('User');
        $this->db->where('email', $mail);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query;
```

As far as I know, $query is an array (a set of results), I want to retrieve an specific value of a field in that array to return it or to assign it to another variable, the question is HOW?

I'd like to do something like this

```
$value = $query['first_field_of_resultset'];
return $value;
```

Comment: `$query` there is actually a `CI_DB_mysql_result` object, which you can call methods on to return the results, which are stored in an `result_object` property.

Comment: And how do I use its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending Johns answer, you need to cover yourself in case nothing comes back
so in your model method:

```
// make sure we have a result
if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) 
{  
// assign the result 
$user = $query->row();  
// pull out the field you want 
$value = $user->first_field_of_resultset;
// return it
return $value ; 
}
else { return FALSE; }
```

Then in your controller, say if the model is called user_model

```
if(! $value = $this->user_model->getUser($email) )
{
 // boo hoo no results
} 
else
{
// success
}
```

And of course this assumes you have run $email through CI form validation to make sure it is a valid email -- before sending to your database.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a bunch of different ways to get the results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html). Here's one:

```
$user = $query->row(); 
echo $user->first_field_of_resultset;
```

If you prefer arrays:

```
$user = $query->row_array();
echo $user['first_field_of_resultset'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first row you can do:

```
$row = $query->first_row();
```

But I don't know why you are retreaving all fields if you only need just one column:

```
$this->db->select('user.the_column_to_select');
```

Answer (score 0):

$query is an object. So in order to get the results as an array you need to do the following.

```
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
$email = $this->db->select('email')->from('users')->where(array(
      'userID' => $userID))->limit(1)->get()->row('email');

// $email will either be the email address you're looking for or FALSE
```